Why is my Kafka Streams app failing on deserialization errors despite cnfg StreamsDeserializationErrorHandler to CONTINUE in KafkaConfiguration?
I'm working on a Kafka Streams application with a custom StreamsDeserializationErrorHandler that extends RecoveringDeserializationExceptionHandler. My setup includes:
A deserialization error handler that decides whether to FAIL or CONTINUE based on the type of exception.
A ConsumerRecordRecoverer that forwards deserialization failures to a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) topic.
In my deserialization logic, I'm throwing a GlobalException (which extends Exception) when specific errors occur. Within StreamsDeserializationErrorHandler, I check for instances of GlobalException and log them, returning DeserializationHandlerResponse.CONTINUE to allow the stream to skip the problematic record and continue processing.
However, despite setting the handler response to CONTINUE, the application still fails when a deserialization error occurs. The error message indicates that the deserialization error handler is not configured, even though I have specified it in my Kafka configuration.

@Bean
public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kstreamConfig() {
    Map<String, Object> streamProperties = kafkaProperties.buildStreamsProperties();
    
    // Setting default deserialization and production exception handlers
    streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, StreamsDeserializationErrorHandler.class);
    streamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, StreamsRecordProducerErrorHandler.class);
    
    // Other configuration settings as needed
    return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(streamProperties);
}

I  also have a setupTransactionKafkaStream method in KafkaConfiguration, but I'm not entirely sure how it interacts with the configuration above. Here’s the method:
@Bean("orderStreams")
public KafkaStreams setupOrderKafkaStream(final StreamsBuilder streamBuilder, 
                                          OrderTopology orderPipeline) {
    orderPipeline.process(streamBuilder);
    KafkaStreams orderStream = new KafkaStreams(streamBuilder.build(), kstreamConfig().asProperties());
    orderStream.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new KafkaStreamExceptionHandler());
    return orderStream;
}


Hard to say. It's a know bug that the "ProductionExceptionHandler" does not work with EOS enabled (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-15259); but the "DeserializationExceptionHandler" should work. What version of Kafka Streams are you using? -- Given that you are using Spring, are you sure your config is pickedup correctly by Kafka Streams (on startup, KafakStreams would log the effective StreamsConfig, so maybe verify if your custom handler is picked up).
